# How to customize TabLayout tabs separately?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tabs

This is my TabLayout xml code:

> ```
>     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>         app:tabBackground="@drawable/profile_tab_selector"
>         android:id="@+id/profileTabLayout"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="28dp"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
>         app:tabGravity="fill"
>         app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
>         app:tabMode="fixed"
>         app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
>         app:tabTextColor="@color/white">
>     </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
> ```

And this one is for *tabBackground="@drawable/profile_tab_selector"*:

> ```
> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>  <item android:state_selected="true">
>     <shape>
>         <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white"/>
>         <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
>     </shape>
>  </item>
>  <item>
>     <shape>
>         <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white"/>
>         <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
>     </shape>
>  </item> 
> </selector>
> ```

I want to design it like this, with rounded cornenrs:

[image]

The problem is that in selector I can not detect the first and the last tabs to modify them. And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have given the shape in the `drawable` file , but you didn't give corner radius.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
  <stroke
     android:width="10dp"
     android:color="@android:color/transparent"></stroke>
  <solid android:color="#23cf5a" />
 </shape>
```

And you can design something like this too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
    android:radius="32dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topRightRadius="16dp" />

<solid android:color="@color/tab_color" />

<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />

<size
    android:height="32dp" />


</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Your Solution is here**

**Don't Use**  : app:tabBackground="@drawable/profile_tab_selector"

**Use** : android:background="@drawable/profile_tab_selector"

You also try it.